# How to install third-party modules in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

It is clear how to install roles, but what about modules? Let's say I have a few projects where I have part of script that could be nicely automated by self-made module. How can I install/update it in all projects without copy paste?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If scripts are located inside your project, then consider [including files](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#task-include-files-and-encouraging-reuse) or [using dependencies](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_roles.html#role-dependencies)

If you need already made module, consider using [Ansible Galaxy](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/galaxy.html)

Otherwise you can [create own module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dev_guide/developing_modules.html) or even [plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html).

Comment: so I nee to put plugin to role?

Comment: Yes, you can make a role that contains only module. See `role_with_module` example [here](https://github.com/berlic/devopsdays-ansible).